# DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 43 row(s)' when updating entities

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to update database data but I'm facing a problem that I've never seen before. I usually use this approach to update data, but this time I got this error and I would like to better understand why and how to solve it:

```
//this entity has a primary key consisting of 3 columns in the database
var exists =  await _context.Relatives
    .Where(x => x.Company== companyId)
    .Where(x => x.Person== personId)
    .Where(x => x.Cpf == familiar.Cpf)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (exists != default)
{
    exists.Cpf = familiar.Cpf;
    exists.Nome = familiar.Name;
    //there are other props here
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When executing `SaveChangesAsync()`, this error appears: `Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 43 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded`. Could someone help me better understand which part of my code is generating this error?

When doing `_context.Relatives.Update(exists)` before `SaveChangesAsync()`, the following error appears: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'RH_PK_3160'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.X'`, and I didn't update any of the primary keys, only other properties.

Comment: _context.Relatives.Update(exists); then SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: When doing this, the following error appears: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'RH_PK_3160'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.X'`, and I didn't update any of the primary keys, only other properties.

Comment: Probably `Relatives` has bad PK defined.